# Rails link_to calls helper method and loads the variables used in modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, helper, link-to

I'm trying to show the user profile of commenters in a modal. So when the user clicks on the "username" above the comment made, a modal pops-up with the appropriate user profile info. I try to pass in (comment.id) parameter to my helper method, then return the user profile for each commenter, which I use in my modal view.

My helper:

```
def getuserprofileofcommenter(commentid) 

  specific_comment = Comment.where("id = ?", commentid)

  specific_comment.each do |comment|
    @commenter = Userprofile.find_by("id = ?", comment.userprofile_id)
  end

end
```

My modal (in view):

```
<div id="commenterModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
...
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
          <p style="font-weight: bold;"><%= @commenter.user_description %></p>
          <p><%= @commenter.bio %></p>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">OK</button>
</div>
...
```

My view:

```
<%= link_to "username", getuserprofileofcommenter(comment.id), :class => "btn", :remote => false, "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#commenterModal" %>
```

The link_to seems to be taking my helper method as a path. When I click on the link "username", a modal pops-up but with the first commenter's profile and then redirects to comment_path in the modal. I can't seem to get the correct user profile info in the modal.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your helper method doesn't return a user profile, it returns a `specific_comment`.

The **last statement** in the method is its return value. The fact that you assign to `@commenter` is completely irrelevant.

Your last statement is `specific_comment.where(...)`, and the result of that statement is `specific_comment` itself. If you want to return the user (or "commenter") for the comment, you need to actually *return* it, not just assign it to an instance variable.

As an aside, you're misusing `where` and `each`. You're finding a record by ID, there is no need to use `where` or iterate over a result set. If you've set up your associations correctly, your entire method should look like this:

```
def getuserprofileofcommenter(commentid) 
  Comment.find(commentid).userprofile
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think I iterated because I didn't understand why the result only gave me the first "commenter". Your helper method makes a lot of sense and I'm using it as <%= getuserprofileofcommenter(comment.id).bio %> in my modal. However, the comment.id does not seem to be updating in the modal and I am only able to get the **first** "commenter's" user profile.